# Add programmatically Visual Studio Solution and Projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, envdte, visual-studio-project

I am trying to generate a Visual Studio 2010 solution and add VS 2010 projects from custom templates!

My requirement:
1. Generate a VisualStudio Solution 2010, Save it to a folder, add VisualSTudio Project from my own templates (I have 3 different templates: ClassLibrary,WinForms ,WCFService)

My issue:
I implemented something that is working half a way!

1. Solution is created correctly but the content of the ".sln" file is very poor! No project reference is added >
2. In the root folder, it creates a Solution also for the C# Project, which I do not want. I want only the MainSolution file. (In my case "TestSolution.sln"). How can I stop creating a solutionfile for each project created?

Below the source code I use:
//for The solution:
[image]

//adding a project
[image]

Am I using the wrong interfaces? 
Why the  `vs2010Solution.AddFromTemplate(..)` returns `null` after the call, but no exception is thrown? Also the Project is created correctly in the folderstructure! But at runtime I can't check the list of projects "vs2010Solution.Projects" as it is `null`! (After correctly adding a project). I need the Project added because I need to add some references programmatically, which I try to do in the next line, but it doesn't work because `vs2010Project` is `null`).

So I am trying to wrap the VisualStudio 2010 automation model, to create a solution and add projects! But is not really working! Do I need to cast EnvDTE.Project to "VSLangProj.Project" at some point? I want to create a clean wrapper for VS2010, after that one for VS 2012! 
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide text code instead of images.

Comment: Screenshots of your code? Really?

Answer (score 0):

See the several articles of the section "Articles about automating project creation" on my web site:

http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/articles/add-ins/

They explain why AddFromTemplate method returns null, how to create a solution, a project, a project inside a solution folder, a project item, etc.

Comment: Thx Carlos, I solved partally the issue! Now I can generate a Soluton, add 4 projects andalso 2 references for each projects (With a test). The issue is that while running the tests in debug mode, everything works fine! As soon as I try to run the source code, it adds only one project to the solution and then it quits!